# Check if a String Column has only certain list of characters PySpark

Tags: regex, pyspark

I am trying to check if a string column contains only certain list of characters and no other characters in PySpark

this is what I have been trying
Code

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

# Define a regular expression that matches only allowed characters
allowed_chars_regex = "^[0SU-1?]+$"

# Apply the regular expression to the string column using rlike
RPT_AR = RPT_AR.filter(col("Last12MonthsPaymentStatus").rlike(allowed_chars_regex))
```

basically search for these 5 characters 0(Zero), S, U, -1, and ?

My Original Table is as below

```
+------------------------------------+
|Last12MonthsPaymentStatus           |
+------------------------------------+
|000?000000000000000000?00?0000000000|
|SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS0000000000000000S0S|
|S???????00000000000SS?0000000000000?|
|DDDDDDDDDDDDDD?DDDDDDDDBBB?BBBBBBBBS|
|0?000???????????????????????????????|
|DDD????DDDDDDD?DD0000DDBBB?BBBBBBBBS|
|S10SSSSSSSSSSS??????????????????????|
|S10SSSSSSSSSSSS?????????????????????|
+------------------------------------+
```

and the Output I expect is as below

```
+------------------------------------+
|Last12MonthsPaymentStatus           |
+------------------------------------+
|000?000000000000000000?00?0000000000|
|SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS0000000000000000S0S|
|S???????00000000000SS?0000000000000?|
|0?000???????????????????????????????|
|S10SSSSSSSSSSS??????????????????????|
|S10SSSSSSSSSSSS?????????????????????|
+------------------------------------+
```

It is throwing **Py4JJavaError**

Comment: Could you add your sample data and expected output in textual format instead?

Comment: Done with the required change

Comment: `-1` is not a symbol, but rather 2 symbols: are strings like `1-0` allowed? Class `[0SU-1?]` is invalid: `-` should be last (or first) in class.

Comment: Tweaking the allowed characters should do the job. Just use `allowed_chars_regex = "^[0SU\-\?1]+$"` instead. The reason you're getting this error is because of the escape character as it is unable to identify `hyphen (-)` and `question mark (?)` characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

n the regular expression "^[0SU-?1]+$", the backslash character () is used to escape the hyphen (-) and question mark (?) characters.

In regular expressions, the hyphen character has a special meaning when it is used inside a character class (i.e., inside square brackets). It indicates a range of characters to match. For example, the character class [A-Z] matches any uppercase letter from A to Z. However, when you want to match a literal hyphen character inside a character class, you need to escape it with a backslash.

So, in the regular expression "^[0SU-?1]+$", the backslashes are used to escape the hyphen and question mark characters so that they are interpreted as literal characters to match, rather than having their special meanings in the regular expression syntax.

See the below implementation for details-

**Input Dataframe**

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType

# Define the input table as a list of tuples
input_data = [
    ("000?000000000000000000?00?0000000000",),
    ("SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS0000000000000000S0S",),
    ("S???????00000000000SS?0000000000000?",),
    ("DDDDDDDDDDDDDD?DDDDDDDDBBB?BBBBBBBBS",),
    ("0?000???????????????????????????????",),
    ("DDD????DDDDDDD?DD0000DDBBB?BBBBBBBBS",),
    ("S10SSSSSSSSSSS??????????????????????",),
    ("S10SSSSSSSSSSSS?????????????????????",)
]

# Define the schema for the DataFrame
schema = StructType([
    StructField("Last12MonthsPaymentStatus", StringType(), True)
])

# Create a SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("CreateDataFrame").getOrCreate()

# Create the DataFrame from the input data and schema
df = spark.createDataFrame(input_data, schema)

# Show the DataFrame
df.show(truncate=False)

+------------------------------------+
|Last12MonthsPaymentStatus           |
+------------------------------------+
|000?000000000000000000?00?0000000000|
|SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS0000000000000000S0S|
|S???????00000000000SS?0000000000000?|
|DDDDDDDDDDDDDD?DDDDDDDDBBB?BBBBBBBBS|
|0?000???????????????????????????????|
|DDD????DDDDDDD?DD0000DDBBB?BBBBBBBBS|
|S10SSSSSSSSSSS??????????????????????|
|S10SSSSSSSSSSSS?????????????????????|
+------------------------------------+
```

**Output Dataframe**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

# Define a regular expression that matches only allowed characters
allowed_chars_regex = "^[0SU\-\?1]+$"

# Apply the regular expression to the string column using rlike
df1 = df.filter(col("Last12MonthsPaymentStatus").rlike(allowed_chars_regex))
df1.show(truncate=False)
+------------------------------------+
|Last12MonthsPaymentStatus           |
+------------------------------------+
|000?000000000000000000?00?0000000000|
|SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS0000000000000000S0S|
|S???????00000000000SS?0000000000000?|
|0?000???????????????????????????????|
|S10SSSSSSSSSSS??????????????????????|
|S10SSSSSSSSSSSS?????????????????????|
+------------------------------------+
```